# How to select only one tag to fill date frame in a scrape?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests

In Python 3, I need to scrape tables on a website:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

res = requests.get("http://portal.stf.jus.br/processos/listarPartes.asp?termo=paulo%20salim%20maluf")

soup =  BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

parts = soup.find_all('table', {'class': 'table m-b-0'})

print(parts)

[<table class="table m-b-0"> <th>Identificação</th> <th>Número Único</th> <th>Data Autuação</th> <th>Meio</th> <th>Publicidade</th> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1455705">Inq 138</a></td> <td>0000344-45.1983.0.01.0000</td> <td>29/04/1983</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1458035">Inq 170</a></td> <td>0000243-71.1984.0.01.0000</td> <td>23/03/1984</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1460780">Inq 202</a></td> <td>0000199-18.1985.0.01.0000</td> <td>26/02/1985</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1463215">Inq 228</a></td> <td>0001497-45.1985.0.01.0000</td> <td>04/11/1985</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1463278">Inq 229</a></td> <td>0001526-95.1985.0.01.0000</td> <td>11/11/1985</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2547059">AP 449</a></td> <td>0004490-89.2007.0.01.0000</td> <td>14/08/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1471162">Inq 351</a></td> <td>0001562-69.1987.0.01.0000</td> <td>09/09/1987</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1740074">Inq 1430</a></td> <td>0004092-60.1998.0.01.0000</td> <td>04/12/1998</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1828698">Inq 1644</a></td> <td>0002280-12.2000.0.01.0000</td> <td>27/06/2000</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1654821">Inq 1249</a></td> <td>0003249-66.1996.0.01.0000</td> <td>18/11/1996</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1656655">Inq 1268</a></td> <td>0003587-40.1996.0.01.0000</td> <td>20/12/1996</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2507567">Inq 2518</a></td> <td>0001854-53.2007.0.01.0000</td> <td>16/04/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2095269">Inq 1901</a></td> <td>0000494-25.2003.0.01.0000</td> <td>12/02/2003</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2492743">Inq 2469</a></td> <td>0000746-86.2007.0.01.0000</td> <td>21/02/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2043710">Inq 1837</a></td> <td>0002951-64.2002.0.01.0000</td> <td>16/08/2002</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2257373">Rcl 2980</a></td> <td>0004831-23.2004.0.01.0000</td> <td>23/11/2004</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2257351">Rcl 2984</a></td> <td>0004822-61.2004.0.01.0000</td> <td>23/11/2004</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1878794">Pet 2188</a></td> <td>0003954-25.2000.0.01.0000</td> <td>14/11/2000</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2296897">Rcl 3338</a></td> <td>0002065-60.2005.0.01.0000</td> <td>18/05/2005</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2502232">Pet 3923</a></td> <td>0001447-47.2007.0.01.0000</td> <td>23/03/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2496217">Pet 3891</a></td> <td>0000957-25.2007.0.01.0000</td> <td>05/03/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2511735">Pet 3960</a></td> <td>0002077-06.2007.0.01.0000</td> <td>26/04/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2646528">Pet 4466</a></td> <td>0006782-13.2008.0.01.0000</td> <td>07/11/2008</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2550348">Pet 4132</a></td> <td>0004655-39.2007.0.01.0000</td> <td>23/08/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2549919">Pet 4133</a></td> <td>0004636-33.2007.0.01.0000</td> <td>23/08/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2485622">Rcl 4899</a></td> <td>0000244-50.2007.0.01.0000</td> <td>18/01/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2549328">MS 26863</a></td> <td>0004617-27.2007.0.01.0000</td> <td>22/08/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1615787">HC 72731</a></td> <td>0001236-31.1995.0.01.0000</td> <td>18/05/1995</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1438260">RE 77205</a></td> <td> </td> <td>02/08/1973</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2326349">HC 86828</a></td> <td>0004531-27.2005.0.01.0000</td> <td>29/09/2005</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2324699">HC 86759</a></td> <td>0004378-91.2005.0.01.0000</td> <td>22/09/2005</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2330454">HC 86964</a></td> <td>0004857-84.2005.0.01.0000</td> <td>18/10/2005</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2330831">HC 86991</a></td> <td>0004913-20.2005.0.01.0000</td> <td>20/10/2005</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1450385">RE 93293</a></td> <td> </td> <td>23/09/1980</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2659893">HC 97511</a></td> <td>0000296-75.2009.0.01.0000</td> <td>19/01/2009</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1553416">AI 148897</a></td> <td> </td> <td>27/11/1992</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1625874">AI 176743</a></td> <td> </td> <td>02/10/1995</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1719177">AI 223221</a></td> <td> </td> <td>09/07/1998</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1742963">RE 242546</a></td> <td> </td> <td>21/12/1998</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1886488">AI 323305</a></td> <td> </td> <td>01/12/2000</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2119361">AI 446706</a></td> <td> </td> <td>02/05/2003</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2136833">AI 457100</a></td> <td> </td> <td>24/06/2003</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2202205">AI 495324</a></td> <td> </td> <td>13/02/2004</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2193004">AI 489263</a></td> <td> </td> <td>07/01/2004</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2202682">AI 495714</a></td> <td> </td> <td>17/02/2004</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2302168">AI 548966</a></td> <td> </td> <td>07/06/2005</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2500686">RE 540712</a></td> <td> </td> <td>19/03/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2594212">RE 577771</a></td> <td> </td> <td>13/02/2008</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2585030">RE 574636</a></td> <td> </td> <td>31/12/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2328209">AI 564510</a></td> <td> </td> <td>06/10/2005</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2339607">AI 556727</a></td> <td> </td> <td>30/11/2005</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2327939">AI 564740</a></td> <td> </td> <td>06/10/2005</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2577541">RE 571596</a></td> <td> </td> <td>21/11/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2576950">RE 571366</a></td> <td> </td> <td>19/11/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2575548">RE 570742</a></td> <td> </td> <td>12/11/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2422042">AI 610979</a></td> <td> </td> <td>04/10/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2425103">AI 613045</a></td> <td> </td> <td>10/10/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2438074">AI 620055</a></td> <td> </td> <td>06/11/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2429261">AI 613330</a></td> <td> </td> <td>18/10/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2421798">AI 613011</a></td> <td> </td> <td>04/10/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2428282">AI 614436</a></td> <td> </td> <td>16/10/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2422311">AI 611851</a></td> <td> </td> <td>04/10/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2416702">AI 607605</a></td> <td> </td> <td>22/09/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2395268">AI 596356</a></td> <td> </td> <td>28/07/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2456727">AI 631129</a></td> <td> </td> <td>03/12/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2463210">AI 632771</a></td> <td> </td> <td>10/12/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2533130">AI 668455</a></td> <td> </td> <td>28/06/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2440814">AI 623286</a></td> <td> </td> <td>10/11/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2442092">AI 623444</a></td> <td> </td> <td>14/11/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2509817">AI 656365</a></td> <td> </td> <td>23/04/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2476685">AI 634273</a></td> <td> </td> <td>29/12/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2470012">AI 637744</a></td> <td> </td> <td>17/12/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2463558">AI 635450</a></td> <td> </td> <td>11/12/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2568713">AI 688217</a></td> <td> </td> <td>22/10/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2562790">AI 685015</a></td> <td> </td> <td>02/10/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2569031">AI 688019</a></td> <td> </td> <td>22/10/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2540446">AI 673117</a></td> <td> </td> <td>20/07/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2500687">AI 651181</a></td> <td> </td> <td>19/03/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2497975">AI 649978</a></td> <td> </td> <td>09/03/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2626718">AI 720168</a></td> <td> </td> <td>25/06/2008</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2626965">AI 720220</a></td> <td> </td> <td>26/06/2008</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2613005">AI 712490</a></td> <td> </td> <td>25/04/2008</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2544337">AI 675174</a></td> <td> </td> <td>03/08/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2584538">AI 696448</a></td> <td> </td> <td>19/12/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2571097">AI 689113</a></td> <td> </td> <td>26/10/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2586710">AI 697555</a></td> <td> </td> <td>07/01/2008</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2605248">AI 708183</a></td> <td> </td> <td>25/03/2008</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2657612">AI 739587</a></td> <td> </td> <td>28/12/2008</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2260296">AI 526303</a></td> <td> </td> <td>07/12/2004</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2478066">RE 525709</a></td> <td> </td> <td>03/01/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1456481">AR 1178</a></td> <td>0000716-91.1983.0.01.0000</td> <td>01/09/1983</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2549780">MS 26865</a></td> <td>0004635-48.2007.0.01.0000</td> <td>22/08/2007</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=1553329">AI 130440</a></td> <td> </td> <td>26/11/1992</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> </table>, <table class="table m-b-0"> <th>Identificação</th> <th>Número Único</th> <th>Data Autuação</th> <th>Meio</th> <th>Publicidade</th> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2361001">RE 479887</a></td> <td> </td> <td>10/02/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2356786">AI 575141</a></td> <td> </td> <td>30/01/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2328195">AI 575232</a></td> <td> </td> <td>06/10/2005</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2328435">AI 575233</a></td> <td> </td> <td>07/10/2005</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2352434">AI 576333</a></td> <td> </td> <td>16/01/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2426607">AI 612917</a></td> <td> </td> <td>12/10/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2403983">AI 602157</a></td> <td> </td> <td>26/08/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2405437">AI 602232</a></td> <td> </td> <td>29/08/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2409644">AI 606013</a></td> <td> </td> <td>06/09/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2387750">AI 594486</a></td> <td> </td> <td>29/06/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2392559">AI 596041</a></td> <td> </td> <td>18/07/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2401944">AI 600394</a></td> <td> </td> <td>21/08/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2460928">AI 634236</a></td> <td> </td> <td>08/12/2006</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2685165">AI 758671</a></td> <td> </td> <td>18/06/2009</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2681567">AI 755758</a></td> <td> </td> <td>03/06/2009</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2666988">AI 745737</a></td> <td> </td> <td>13/03/2009</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2692858">AI 763900</a></td> <td> </td> <td>30/07/2009</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=2682032">AI 756173</a></td> <td> </td> <td>04/06/2009</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=3801415">AI 777535</a></td> <td> </td> <td>23/11/2009</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=3857683">AI 793282</a></td> <td> </td> <td>24/03/2010</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=3808261">AI 779401</a></td> <td> </td> <td>06/12/2009</td><td>Eletrônico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=3801415">AI 777535</a></td> <td> </td> <td>23/11/2009</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=3794186">RE 605763</a></td> <td> </td> <td>10/11/2009</td><td>Eletrônico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=3976751">AI 824064</a></td> <td> </td> <td>28/10/2010</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=3928453">AI 811146</a></td> <td> </td> <td>05/08/2010</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=4013879">AI 833777</a></td> <td> </td> <td>05/01/2011</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=4103266">ARE 647372</a></td> <td> </td> <td>28/06/2011</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=4493159">ARE 783482</a></td> <td> </td> <td>08/11/2013</td><td>Eletrônico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=4357102">Inq 3601</a></td> <td>9930137-38.2013.1.00.0000</td> <td>29/01/2013</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=4383586">Inq 3638</a></td> <td>9955034-33.2013.1.00.0000</td> <td>22/03/2013</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=4348033">Pet 5019</a></td> <td>9985912-29.2012.0.01.0000</td> <td>14/12/2012</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=4353433">ARE 730457</a></td> <td> </td> <td>14/01/2013</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=4886605">AP 968</a></td> <td>9930137-38.2013.1.00.0000</td> <td>17/11/2015</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=4962320">ARE 962505</a></td> <td> </td> <td>11/04/2016</td><td>Físico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=5308934">ARE 1092382</a></td> <td>2029851-65.2014.8.26.0000</td> <td>16/11/2017</td><td>Eletrônico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> </table>, <table class="table m-b-0"> <th>Identificação</th> <th>Número Único</th> <th>Data Autuação</th> <th>Meio</th> <th>Publicidade</th> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=5335633">HC 151913</a></td> <td>0016064-06.2017.1.00.0000</td> <td>21/12/2017</td><td>Eletrônico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=5335218">AC 4373</a></td> <td>0016050-22.2017.1.00.0000</td> <td>20/12/2017</td><td>Eletrônico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=5345284">HC 152707</a></td> <td>0065290-43.2018.1.00.0000</td> <td>01/02/2018</td><td>Eletrônico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=5335653">HC 151919</a></td> <td>0016071-95.2017.1.00.0000</td> <td>21/12/2017</td><td>Eletrônico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=5336212">HC 152016</a></td> <td>0016194-93.2017.1.00.0000</td> <td>27/12/2017</td><td>Eletrônico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=5340021">HC 152385</a></td> <td>0064793-29.2018.1.00.0000</td> <td>16/01/2018</td><td>Eletrônico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="detalhe.asp?incidente=5342631">ARE 1104590</a></td> <td>0400459-17.1996.8.26.0053</td> <td>29/01/2018</td><td>Eletrônico</td><td>Público</td> </tr> </table>]
```

This site has three tables (table class = "table m-b-0")

Each has the headers "Identificacao", "Numero_Unico", "Data_Autuacao", "Meio" and "Publicidade"

As print shows, the information I'm looking for is in several "td"

My idea was to capture all  and then iterate through them ao populate a dataframe with the the value in the rows, with the use of pandas

With values like these:

```
identificacao = 'Inq 138'
identificacao_link = 'http://portal.stf.jus.br/processos/detalhe.asp?incidente=1455705'
numero_unico = '0000344-45.1983.0.01.0000'
data_autuacao = '29/04/1983'
meio = 'Físico'
publicidade = 'Público'
...
...
```

But I got this error message when I tried to capture the "td":

```
lines = parts.find_all('td')

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-3885de8e7363> in <module>()
----> 1 lines = parts.find_all('td')

~/Documentos/Code/raspa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/element.py in __getattr__(self, key)
   1805     def __getattr__(self, key):
   1806         raise AttributeError(
-> 1807             "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
   1808         )

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Please, does anyone know a method for capturing all  for iteration next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states you are working with a ResultSet here, that doesn't have the attribute `find_all`.

In other words: You can't call `find_all` on your variable `parts`.

You need to iterate over `parts` and call `find_all` on its members for this to work.

```
for part in parts:
    lines = part.find_all('td')
```